# how to fix Drag end Drop Error in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I designed user control using XsltListViewWebPart. I want to upload file using drag end drop.
However I encountered an error. How to fix it?
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does the user logged in have Add Items, and is the list's advanced settings set to "Create and edit all items"?

Comment: When i add file with using list, it is success. However, i want to add filen using user control. it is fail. i encountered drang and drop error.